# Large number of database reads while calling procedure using Entity Framework 4

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, stored-procedures

In my asp.net c# application I am calling a procedure using entity framework 4.0 my problem is that on live site I receive time out issue (it takes more than 1 min to complete execution)

But same procedure when I call from management studio (sql server 2012) it takes hardly 6 sec (even after using `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` and `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`).

When investigated problem it is found that number of reads is to high when I am calling procedure using entity framework.Please se two screen shots.

Entity Framework call Trace..

[image]

Management Studio Trace
[image]

I am not sure why there is so much difference in performance when calling using Entity Framework and while calling from Management studio same procedure.

I want to avoid  `WITH RECOMPILE` option which is the answer in few thread we get.

Can anyone kindly help me , what is the reason of it as well as what is the ideal way to handle such scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason `with recompile` is suggested is it is one of the methods of correcting your issue.  This looks like a parameter sniffing issue, the mentioned method is one way to get around it.  Information on parameter sniffing:

http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/

The reason you could see such a difference between EF and SSMS is due to query options being automatically passed in when calling from the web (be it from EF or ADO or whatever) - especially `ANSI_NULLs` and/or `quoted_identifier`.

Methods of alleviating parameter sniffing as taken from:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3257/different-approaches-to-correct-sql-server-parameter-sniffing/

1. Create SQL Server Stored Procedures using the WITH RECOMPILE Option
2. Use the SQL Server Hint OPTION (RECOMPILE)
3. Use the SQL Server Hint OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR)
4. Use Dummy Variables on SQL Server Stored Procedures
5. Disable SQL Server Parameter Sniffing at the Instance Level
6. Disable Parameter Sniffing for a Specific SQL Server Query
7. I don't think it's listed in the above article, but in 2008 and above you can utilize `optimize for unknown` - related to 3 in the list above, but with better results (potentially)